# How to start the circular recycler view from first item in center

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, circular-dependency

I am using Turn layout manager to make my recyclerview circular everything is working fine, except I want the list to start from the first item in the center and end at the last item at the center, I tried giving margin and padding but did not work

[image]

```
/**
 * An extension of {@link LinearLayoutManager}, where each list item can be offset along a circular
 * trajectory.
 */

    public class TurnLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    
        private static final int MIN_RADIUS = 0;
        private static final int MIN_PEEK = 0;
    
        /**
         * Valid gravity settings for a {@link TurnLayoutManager}.  This defines the direction of the center point
         * around which items will rotate.
         */
        @IntDef(value = {
                Gravity.START,
                Gravity.END
        })
        public @interface Gravity {
            int START = android.view.Gravity.START;
            int END = android.view.Gravity.END;
        }
    
        /**
         * Orientation as defined in {@link RecyclerView}
         */
        @IntDef(value = {
                Orientation.VERTICAL,
                Orientation.HORIZONTAL
        })
        public @interface Orientation {
            int VERTICAL = RecyclerView.VERTICAL;
            int HORIZONTAL = RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL;
        }
    
        @Gravity
        private int gravity;
        @Dimension
        private int radius;
        @Dimension
        private int peekDistance;
        private boolean rotate;
        private Point center;
    
        /**
         * Define a new {@link TurnLayoutManager} with the given settings.<br>
         * {@code gravity} and {@code orientation} combine to define the curvature of the turn:
         * <br><br>
         * {@link Gravity#START}<br>
         * {@link Orientation#VERTICAL}
         * <pre>
         *     ┏─────────┓
         *     ┃ x       ┃
         *     ┃  x      ┃
         *     ┃   x     ┃
         *     ┃   x     ┃
         *     ┃   x     ┃
         *     ┃  x      ┃
         *     ┃ x       ┃
         *     ┗─────────┛
         * </pre>
         * <br>
         * {@link Gravity#END}<br>
         * {@link Orientation#VERTICAL}
         * <pre>
         *     ┏─────────┓
         *     ┃       x ┃
         *     ┃      x  ┃
         *     ┃     x   ┃
         *     ┃     x   ┃
         *     ┃     x   ┃
         *     ┃      x  ┃
         *     ┃       x ┃
         *     ┗─────────┛
         * </pre>
         * <p>
         * <br>
         * {@link Gravity#START}<br>
         * {@link Orientation#HORIZONTAL}
         * <pre>
         *     ┏─────────┓
         *     ┃x       x┃
         *     ┃ x     x ┃
         *     ┃   xxx   ┃
         *     ┃         ┃
         *     ┃         ┃
         *     ┃         ┃
         *     ┃         ┃
         *     ┗─────────┛
         * </pre>
         * <p>
         * <br>
         * {@link Gravity#END}<br>
         * {@link Orientation#HORIZONTAL}
         * <pre>
         *     ┏─────────┓
         *     ┃         ┃
         *     ┃         ┃
         *     ┃         ┃
         *     ┃         ┃
         *     ┃   xxx   ┃
         *     ┃ x     x ┃
         *     ┃x       x┃
         *     ┗─────────┛
         * </pre>
         *
         * @param gravity      The {@link Gravity} that will define where the anchor point is for this layout manager.  The
         *                     gravity point is the point around which items orbit.
         * @param orientation  The orientation as defined in {@link RecyclerView}, and enforced by {@link Orientation}
         * @param radius       The radius of the rotation angle, which helps define the curvature of the turn.  This value
         *                     will be clamped to {@code [0, MAX_INT]} inclusive.
         * @param peekDistance The absolute extra distance from the {@link Gravity} edge after which this layout manager will start
         *                     placing items.  This value will be clamped to {@code [0, radius]} inclusive.
         * @param rotate       Should the items rotate as if on a turning surface, or should they maintain
         *                     their angle with respect to the screen as they orbit the center point?
         */
        public TurnLayoutManager(Context context,
                                 @Gravity int gravity,
                                 @Orientation int orientation,
                                 @Dimension int radius,
                                 @Dimension int peekDistance,
                                 boolean rotate) {
            super(context, orientation, false);
            this.gravity = gravity;
            this.radius = Math.max(radius, MIN_RADIUS);
            this.peekDistance = Math.min(Math.max(peekDistance, MIN_PEEK), radius);
            this.rotate = rotate;
            this.center = new Point();
        }
    
        /**
         * Create a {@link TurnLayoutManager} with default settings for gravity, orientation, and rotation.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public TurnLayoutManager(Context context,
                                 @Dimension int radius,
                                 @Dimension int peekDistance) {
            this(context, Gravity.START, Orientation.VERTICAL, radius, peekDistance, false);
        }
    
        public void setRadius(int radius) {
            this.radius = Math.max(radius, MIN_RADIUS);
            requestLayout();
        }
    
        public void setPeekDistance(int peekDistance) {
            this.peekDistance = Math.min(Math.max(peekDistance, MIN_PEEK), radius);
            requestLayout();
        }
    
        public void setGravity(@Gravity int gravity) {
            this.gravity = gravity;
            requestLayout();
        }
    
        public void setRotate(boolean rotate) {
            this.rotate = rotate;
            requestLayout();
        }
    
        @Override
        public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int by = super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy, recycler, state);
            setChildOffsetsVertical(gravity, radius, center, peekDistance);
            return by;
        }
    
        @Override
        public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int by = super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state);
            setChildOffsetsHorizontal(gravity, radius, center, peekDistance);
            return by;
        }
    
        @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
            super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
            this.center = deriveCenter(gravity, getOrientation(), radius, peekDistance, center);
            setChildOffsets(gravity, getOrientation(), radius, center, peekDistance);
        }
    
        /**
         * Accounting for the settings of {@link Gravity} and {@link Orientation}, find the center point
         * around which this layout manager should arrange list items.  Place the resulting coordinates
         * into {@code out}, to avoid reallocation.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("DuplicateExpressions")
        private Point deriveCenter(@Gravity int gravity,
                                   int orientation,
                                   @Dimension int radius,
                                   @Dimension int peekDistance,
                                   Point out) {
            final int gravitySign = gravity == Gravity.START ? -1 : 1;
            final int distanceMultiplier = gravity == Gravity.START ? 0 : 1;
            int x, y;
            switch (orientation) {
                case Orientation.HORIZONTAL:
                    y = (distanceMultiplier * getHeight()) + gravitySign * (Math.abs(radius - peekDistance));
                    x = getWidth() / 2;
                    break;
                case Orientation.VERTICAL:
                default:
                    y = getHeight() /2;
                    x = (distanceMultiplier * getWidth()) + gravitySign * (Math.abs(radius - peekDistance));
                    break;
            }
            out.set(x, y);
            return out;
        }
    
        /**
         * Find the absolute horizontal distance by which a view at {@code viewY} should offset
         * to align with the circle {@code center} with {@code radius}, accounting for {@code peekDistance}.
         */
        private double resolveOffsetX(double radius, double viewY, Point center, int peekDistance) {
            final double opposite = Math.abs(center.y - viewY);
            final double radiusSquared = radius * radius;
            final double oppositeSquared = opposite * opposite;
            final double adjacentSideLength = Math.sqrt(radiusSquared - oppositeSquared);
            return adjacentSideLength - radius + peekDistance;
        }
    
        /**
         * Find the absolute vertical distance by which a view at {@code viewX} should offset to
         * align with the circle {@code center} with {@code radius}, account for {@code peekDistance}.
         */
        private double resolveOffsetY(double radius, double viewX, Point center, int peekDistance) {
            final double adjacent = Math.abs(center.x - viewX);
            final double radiusSquared = radius * radius;
            final double adjacentSquared = adjacent * adjacent;
            final double oppositeSideLength = Math.sqrt(radiusSquared - adjacentSquared);
            return oppositeSideLength - radius + peekDistance;
        }
    
        /**
         * Traffic method to divert calls based on {@link Orientation}.
         *
         * @see #setChildOffsetsVertical(int, int, Point, int)
         * @see #setChildOffsetsHorizontal(int, int, Point, int)
         */
        private void setChildOffsets(@Gravity int gravity,
                                     int orientation,
                                     @Dimension int radius,
                                     Point center,
                                     int peekDistance) {
            if (orientation == VERTICAL) {
                setChildOffsetsVertical(gravity, radius, center, peekDistance);
            } else if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
                setChildOffsetsHorizontal(gravity, radius, center, peekDistance);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Set the bumper offsets on child views for {@link Orientation#VERTICAL}
         */
        private void setChildOffsetsVertical(@Gravity int gravity,
                                             @Dimension int radius,
                                             Point center,
                                             int peekDistance) {
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                if (child == null) continue;
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                final int xOffset = (int) resolveOffsetX(radius, child.getY() + child.getHeight() / 2.0f, center, peekDistance);
                final int x = gravity == Gravity.START ? xOffset + getMarginStart(layoutParams)
                        : getWidth() - xOffset - child.getWidth() - getMarginStart(layoutParams);
                child.layout(x, child.getTop(), child.getWidth() + x, child.getBottom());
                setChildRotationVertical(gravity, child, radius, center);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Given that the is {@link Orientation#VERTICAL}, apply rotation if rotation is enabled.
         */
        private void setChildRotationVertical(@Gravity int gravity, View child, int radius, Point center) {
            if (!rotate) {
                child.setRotation(0);
                return;
            }
            boolean childPastCenter = (child.getY() + child.getHeight() / 2.0) > center.y;
            float directionMult;
            if (gravity == Gravity.END) {
                directionMult = childPastCenter ? -1 : 1;
            } else {
                directionMult = childPastCenter ? 1 : -1;
            }
            final float opposite = Math.abs(child.getY() + child.getHeight() / 2.0f - center.y);
            child.setRotation((float) (directionMult * Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(opposite / radius))));
        }
    
        /**
         * Set bumper offsets on child views for {@link Orientation#HORIZONTAL}
         */
        private void setChildOffsetsHorizontal(@Gravity int gravity,
                                               @Dimension int radius,
                                               Point center,
                                               int peekDistance) {
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                if (child == null) continue;
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                final int yOffset = (int) resolveOffsetY(radius, child.getX() + child.getWidth() / 2.0f, center, peekDistance);
                final int y = gravity == Gravity.START ? yOffset + getMarginStart(layoutParams)
                        : getHeight() - yOffset - child.getHeight() - getMarginStart(layoutParams);
    
                child.layout(child.getLeft(), y, child.getRight(), child.getHeight() + y);
                setChildRotationHorizontal(gravity, child, radius, center);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Given that the orientation is {@link Orientation#HORIZONTAL}, apply rotation if enabled.
         */
        private void setChildRotationHorizontal(@Gravity int gravity, View child, int radius, Point center) {
            if (!rotate) {
                child.setRotation(0);
                return;
            }
            boolean childPastCenter = (child.getX() + child.getWidth() / 2.0) > center.x;
            float directionMult;
            if (gravity == Gravity.END) {
                directionMult = childPastCenter ? 1 : -1;
            } else {
                directionMult = childPastCenter ? -1 : 1;
            }
            final float opposite = Math.abs(child.getX() + child.getWidth() / 2.0f - center.x);
            child.setRotation((float) (directionMult * Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(opposite / radius))));
        }
    
        /**
         * @see android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams#getMarginStart()
         */
        private int getMarginStart(ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                return layoutParams.getMarginStart();
            }
            return layoutParams.leftMargin;
        }
    }
```